# Android - Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

Tags: android

I have a problem with proguard. i get this on The console 
i use proguard 4.11 .how can i fix this?

```
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Note: there were 4 duplicate class definitions.
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.content.res.ColorStateList depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Warning: there were 12 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
    [2014-02-11 12:46:55 - Distributor] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: The console message gives you two broken links to read up on these two  problems. You can still find the information by going to manual -> troubleshooting on the Proguard page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i added this line to proguard-project.txt

```
    -dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
```

and this line to project.properties

```
   proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: It helps me to create the build but the generated build closed immediately.